# Set a different sdk version on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to set a different sdk version(updated) on my old eclipse.

I go to the `Window>preferences>android>Android>sdk` location
where I browse the folder where my sdk is there, P select it but it does not accept it and gives an error like-

> This Android SDK requires Android Dev...ase update ADT to the latest
>   version.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: welcome to stack over flow, provide more information about your issue

Comment: More information like? @Bhavin

Comment: Do you want a different SDK version or do you want to target different API levels (4.2, 4.4, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

In `default.properties`, change `target` to the new SDK version you want.

Also, in `Manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="minVersion"
    android:targetSdkVersion="targetVersion" />
```

`default.properties` may also be known as `project.properties`. See [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14) for explanation.

> default.properties which is the main project’s properties file
>   containing information such as the build platform target and the
>   library dependencies has been renamed project.properties.

Comment: I get the option project.properties in a project but i dont get the option default.properties, can i know where i get it.

Comment: it creates error in my project like the project was not built,unable to resolve target.Also I want to know that how these settings set the whole sdk version,i mean it is done on any 1 random project.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project name in the left navigator.
Select Properties -> Android and select what sdk you want.

Use the Android SDK Manager to download the latest SDK.